# Programmatic property setting for all maps in Hazelcast?

Tags: java, datagrid, cluster-computing, hazelcast

Is there a way to programmatically set the default "backup-count" property for all distributed maps in Hazelcast?

Using Hazelcast version 3.7.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the default "backup-count" for all maps by using the code below:

```
Config config = new Config();
config.getMapConfig("default").setBackupCount(BACKUP_COUNT);
HazelcastInstance hazelcast = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(config);
```

where the `BACKUP_COUNT` is the backup count you want to set.

Comment: Confirmed, after looking at map statistics